# How to set a date for future in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, sql-timestamp

I am creating a table that has 3 columns one primary key `id` the other one `reg_date` to hold the date that the user has registered and the last one `exp_date` which is 4 years ahead of `reg_date` to hold the expiry date of the account.

How can I set the `exp_date` to `reg_date` + 4 years?

Here's the code I've written so far:

```
CREATE TABLE Accounts (
  id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  reg_date TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  exp_date TIMESTAMP
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way,

```
CREATE TABLE Accounts (
  id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  reg_date TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  exp_date TIMESTAMP generated always as (reg_date + interval 4 year)
)
```